# How to load default values using inner join?

Tags: mysql, database, schema

I have a really simple product inventory. Each products has one or more SKUs.

In the database schema, **Product** is the parent model while **ProductSKUs** is the child model.
A **Product** has the master and default attributes, and **ProductSKUs** can replace this attributes.
Look:

```
--PRODUCT
id
thumbnail_id
gallery
name
slug
description
sku
price
weight
length
height
depth

--PRODUCTSKUS
id
parent_id
thumbnail_id
gallery
name
slug
description
sku
price
weight
length
height
depth
```

What I want to achieve is replace the **Product** fields only when **ProductSKUs** is empty. For example:

A) **Product** has the `thumbnail_id = 10` and **ProductSKUs** `thumbnail_id = null`, then when **SELECT**... **ProductSKUs** will return `thumbnail_id = 10`.

B) **Product** has the `price = 109.99` and **ProductSKUs** `price= null`, then when **SELECT**... **ProductSKUs** will return `price = 109.99`.

C) **Product** has the `price = 109.99` and **ProductSKUs** `price= 99.99`, then when **SELECT**... **ProductSKUs** will return `price = 99.99`.

This simple schema is the best way to achieve this? What SQL INSTRUCTION would be more efficent to get all **ProductSKUs** including the parent default values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use coalesce on each field you want to default:

```
select
    coalesce(productskus.thumbnail_id,product.thumbnail_id) as thumbnail_id,
    ...
from product
join productskus on parent_id=product.id
```